# Get the latest events of a specific type from a specific device

Tags: cumulocity

Is there a way to get the latest event of a specific type from a specific device? So far I queried all events via `myURL/event/events?source=<<ID>>&type=<<type>>`.

Or is there a way to get a collection of events ordered by their creationTime? This could solve my problem too

In the documentation I only found parameters like `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. But what if I don't know the time range of the last event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the support-team:

> currently there is no way to revert the order of events. Besides
>   dateFrom and dateTo you can also use creationFrom and creationTo. This
>   will take the creationTime (server side timestamp when event was
>   created) instead of the time (that is send within the event) But the
>   order will still be oldest -> newest.
>
> Best approach currently would be to use a good estimated time range
>   (so you don't end up with 0 events in the response) where the
>   dateTo/creationTo is in the future. If you add to the query params
>   withTotalPages=true the result will give you the total pages in the
>   statistics part.
>
> Knowing the total pages you can you can do the query again but with
>   currentPage=XX instead of withTotalPages=true and take the last
>   element.
>
> We have this functionality on measurements and audits where you can
>   add the parameter revert=true. I will add an improvement that we
>   extend this to the other APIs but at the moment you are limited to the
>   workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is: /event/events?type={type}&source={source}.

For more information on the available endpoints:
GET /platform

Comment: But this will give me all the events. I'm looking for a way to get only the latest event.

Comment: I thought about to limit the number of events by adding `pageSize=1`, but this won't work because you won't get the latest event (ordered by the creationTime variable).

Comment: Then you can use: /event/events?source={source}&dateFrom={dateFrom}&dateTo={dateTo}&type={type}", however I guess you are not guaranteed to get any events...

Comment: And if i don't know the date range from the last event?

Comment: The other APIs support a parameter revert=true to change the sorting order and get the last measurement. However, it hasn't been added to events. Feel free to ask for such a capability on the support line.

Answer (score 0):

You can just only set the `dateFrom` parameter and the `pageSize` to 1 like so: `&pageSize=1&dateFrom=1970-01-01`. As of September 2017, this returns the most recent event.